# when i change value of particular input, that input's event can only called instead of calling multiple event

Tags: jquery

in below code, i am taking table row dynamically and adding multiple rows and callind change event but it calls multiple events. solution please.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".addnewjewel").click(function(){
                // console.log("a");
                $(".addnewjewelbody").append(`
                    <tr id="${newjewelid}">
                        <td><input type="text" name="jewelname" id="jewelname"></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" id="Gold${newjewelid}" name="jeweltype+${newjewelid}">
                            <label for="Gold${newjewelid}">Gold</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="jeweltype+${newjewelid}" id="Silver${newjewelid}">
                            <label for="Silver${newjewelid}">Silver</label>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="gettotal" name="newjewelweight" value="0" min="0" id="newjewelweight+${newjewelid}" step="0.01"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="gettotal" name="currentrate" value="0" min="0" id="currentrate+${newjewelid}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="gettotal" name="makinhcharge" value="0" min="0" id="makinhcharge+${newjewelid}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="gettotal" name="othercharge" value="0" min="0" id="othercharge+${newjewelid}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="gettotal" name="GrossCharge" value="0" min="0" id="grosscharge+${newjewelid}"></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                `);
                newjeweladded.push(newjewelid);
                newjewelid++;
                console.log(newjewelid);
                console.log(newjeweladded);
                
                $(".gettotal").change(function(){
                    console.log("changed");
                    var grosstotal = 0;
                    var weight = $(this).val()
                    console.log(weight);
                })
            });
```

i am expecting that when i change value of particular input, that input's event can only called instead of calling multiple event.

Comment: Every time you create a new row in the table, you add another `change` listener to *all* the `.gettotal` elements in the table, not just the ones in the row you just added. So when you change something, it will run multiple listeners.

Comment: Use event delegation instead of adding new event handlers when you add a row.